# Getting filename when using TextDirectoryLoader - weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am using the `TextDirectoryLoader` in weka which takes in as an input a directory which has the training data as files arranged in folders and each folder indicates a class label. I pass the **test_example** directory name as an argument. The training part is fine.

Example:

```
+- text_example
    |
    +- class1
    |  |
    |  + file1.txt
    |  |
    |  + file2.txt
    |  |
    |  ...
    |
    +- class2
    |  |
    |  + another_file1.txt
    |  |
    |  + another_file2.txt
    |  |
    |  ...
```

The above illustration borrowed from [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+Weka)

For testing and predicting labels, I create a similar structure.

```
+- predictor_unknowns
    |
    +- unknown
    |  |
    |  + unknownfile1.txt
    |  |
    |  + unknownfile2.txt
    |  |
    |  ...
```

I again pass the director **predictor_unknowns** as an arguement to `TextDirectoryLoader` and I can see the predicting is done fine but I am not sure how to print the file name for which the preidiction is happening. I need to print unknownfile1.txt,unknownfile2.txt etc for which the prediction is happening.

Hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

In weka, those text files and classes become an Instance and the filenames are not saved in Instance class.

Instead, you can get the text content of that file which got classified.

```
double pred = 0d;
Instance current = getInstance();           
pred = classifier.classifyInstance(current);
System.out.println("\nText: "+current.attribute(0)); // Change index according to your dataset
System.out.println("Class: "+tempInstances.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of benefiting others who may have this question, the [documentation for the TextDirectoryLoader](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader.html) explains that you can save the filename as an extra attribute.

On the command line, just add the -F flag.

In Java code, you can use the following line (tdl is an instance of TextDirectoryLoader):

```
tdl.setOutputFilename(true);
```

As long as you do not run the dataset through any filters, each instance will have a string attribute called "filename". If you are planning to run the dataset through filters, it may be useful to use a [FilteredClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) so that you can still access the filename.